# High and low range of a Stock within a day

Tags: stock-analysis

Some stocks make large move within a day.

- What technical indicator that I need to look at in a stock to know
  that daily high low volatility number?
- What is causing the high fluctuation within a day? Is it more selling
  and buying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may not exactly fit your description, you might take a look at the Average True Range indicator (ATR) which provides the  average of true ranges over a specified period of data.  It measures volatility and accounts for price gaps.

If you literally want to see the historical intraday price range for each day or intraday time period (high minus low) then you'll need software that graphs this, a program that offers the High Minus Low Indicator, or a broker that offers the ability to formulate your own scanning criteria (Like ThinkorSwim's ThinkScript).